# Eclipse update failing with numerous errors -- Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Today my Eclipse crashed, when I tried to check if there is some update to fix this crashing (happened more than twice while working)

I got the following error message, unable to upgrade

> 

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Git integration for Eclipse 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
  Software currently installed: Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface 6.1.0.202203080745-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 6.1.0.202203080745-r)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Git integration for Eclipse - UI 6.1.0.202203080745-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 6.1.0.202203080745-r)
    Git integration for Eclipse - UI 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git integration for Eclipse 6.3.0.202209071007-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 6.3.0.202209071007-r)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.egit.ui [6.3.0.202209071007-r,6.3.0.202209071007-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface 6.1.0.202203080745-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 6.1.0.202203080745-r)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui [6.1.0.202203080745-r,6.1.0.202203080745-r]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EGit Mylyn UI 6.1.0.202203080745-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui 6.1.0.202203080745-r)
    To: java.package; org.eclipse.egit.ui [6.1.0,6.2.0)
```

has anyone encountered this issue before?

please share your wisdom or experience.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to uninstall anything related to Mylyn that you find. It has not been updated in some time, and is not compatible with the newer versions of the git support. Once uninstalled, check for updates again.